# Check if variable is instance of ArrayList in SSJS?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have in a SSJS javascript a function that takes in a parameter. In the function I need to check what type of element the parameter is.

I can check for example if that type is an array:

```
if(false == values instanceof Array)
```

I notice that sometimes the incoming parameter is an ArrayList of strings. Is it possible to check against this type also in SSJS?

For now I just convert the object type before I send it to the function.

Comment: Did you try `instanceof ArrayList` or `instanceof List` ? It should work.

Comment: Script interpreter error, line=212, col=43: [ReferenceError] 'ArrayList' not found

Comment: Script interpreter error, line=212, col=43: [ReferenceError] 'List' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with

```
values instanceof java.util.ArrayList
```

or with

```
values instanceof java.util.List
```

if you want to cover all sorts of Java Lists.

Comment: In SSJS you either need to do `importPackage` or use the full Java class name (`java.util.ArrayList` rather than just `ArrayList`). It's one of the key reasons for coding in Java vs SSJS, being able to incorporate standard Java code more easily.